# ExtJS 4 Set Reader

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I have a JSON that used by other parts in application a few times.
To avoid unneeded calls, I want to fetch it ones, and than only use it
where it needs.

the issue is, that JSON cantains a different sections for different parts,
thats why I need to use `root` property.

What I need:
- Proxy that will fetch it ones (One for all)
- Reader for each part, 'cause they use different root
- Store for different parts

**Proxy:**

```
var myProxy = new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
      url: "static/data/myData.json"
});

var operation = new Ext.data.Operation({
      action: "read"
});

myProxy.read(operation);
```

**Some Part:**

```
// try to create custom reader with appropriate root
var reader = new Ext.data.reader.Json({
    root: "table1"
});

// set reader to proxy
myProxy.setReader(reader);

// create store
Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    storeId: "MyStore",
    model: "MyModel",
    autoLoad: true
});

// set proxy to store
Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup("MyStore").setProxy(proxy);
```

Of course, this doesn't work. How I have to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a AJAX fetch to get the JSON, caching it in some variable and then using your store's `loadData` method to fill each store as needed. `loadData` lets you manually add records without going to the remote data source. That'll give you tighter control without having to deal with the proxies; just the readers and stores.